# Can not play local video stream in iOS 7 when airplane mode is on

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I started a local http server to serve video streaming:

```
http://localhost:55736/videos/foo.m3u8
```

And use `MPMoviePlayerController` to play it. It works well in iOS6 no matter whether airplane mode is on or not.

But in iOS 7, when airplane mode is on (or turn off both WIFI and cellular data network), I got the Error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
kind = 1;
new = 2;
old = 0;
```

}

In `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` handler:

```
NSConcreteNotification 0x146c35c0 {
  name = MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification; 
  object = <MPMoviePlayerController: 0x14682b90>;
  userInfo = {
    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey = 1;
    error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800....
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue please tell us if you find something, I'm on it too.

Comment: @freestyler can you tell me how you are streaming videos locally ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. It worked for me

Comment: Does anyone know why this works? Why does localhost not work?

Comment: Looks like Apple broke something in the name resolving code... Resolving localhost shouldn't need a connection ever - it should be in /etc/hosts or equivalent.

Comment: Indeed , It's not the first time that Apple does something funky with name resolving. I encountered a case where if you have a configuration profile - Like Onavo or some other dns changing stuff - it would sometime try to resolve localhost agains the dns instead of accessing the device.   Bummer is this solution doesn't work properly in simulator.... I can live with this.

Comment: This does not solve it for me, has anyone got other suggestions?